# Keeping aspect ratio when height AND width both need to change

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an image resize based on values given to it (width/height)

The values must not exceed the maxheight and maxwidth but must maintain ratio.

Right now it works if I make the height or width too big, but if both are triggered it doesn't work. So it's a logical error, can someone please help me with this.

```
if (maxwidth <= width || maxheight <= height) {

    if(width > maxwidth) {
      var newheight = height * (maxwidth/width);
      newwidth = maxwidth;
      console.log("new height");
    }
    if(height > maxheight) {
      var newwidth = width * (maxheight/height);
      newheight = maxheight;
      console.log("new width");
    }
```

For it in action go here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBEvNO

The error occurs when say width is 1500 and height is 600.

I know it's because the second if statement overwrites the first, but I don't know how to fix this logic.

Comment: Can you add the input and expected output for few different values?

Comment: Basically, the only values I think that have a problem is when the width and height are bigger than what the max is. The height gets adjusted but the width does not. 

So if you try 1500x600 you'll see how it overflows the container its in. I need it to stay within.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, if you do not want the values to exceed their maximums, but do want to scale the image so that it keeps the ratio, you need to set the size values to the maximum before you work out the resulting width/height from that change in width/height.

Second, if you want the ratio to be the same, then you should not be able to change both the height and the width at the same time, because if you change the width, there is exactly one other height value that maintains the ratio

The math for this would be like so:

R = Ratio (Assuming your max values are the ratio you want R = MaxWidth / MaxHeight)

H = Height

W = Width

W = H*R

H = W/R

```
if (maxwidth <= width) {

if(width > maxwidth) {
  newwidth = maxwidth;
  var newheight = newwidth / (maxwidth/maxheight);
  console.log("new height");
}
```

Not only would this need to be changed so that the ratio is a proper ratio but the code you have for making it smaller would also need to be altered.

If by ratio you did not mean the ratio of the original images W/H, please clarify.

For maintaining the inputed user ratio try this:

```
if (maxwidth <= width || maxheight <= height) {
var ratio = width/height;
var heightRatio = height/maxheight;
var widthRatio = width/maxwidth
if(width > maxwidth && widthRatio >= heightRatio) {
  newwidth = maxwidth;
  var newheight = newwidth / ratio;
  console.log("new height");
}
else if(height > maxheight && heightRatio > widthRatio) {
  newheight = maxheight;
  var newwidth = newheight * ratio;
  console.log("new width");
}
```

Checking the larger of the sizes compared to their max size ensures that when the scaling happens, the size largest over the maximum size gets scaled to max, this way the other size does not still go over max at some times

Comment: The image is being generated on the fly. A user inputs values of how big the image is to be and it creates it. The issue is the box the image is created in is only a certain size, so the scale has to be within that box. Basically, I need the image to be created within the box and maintain its true scale.

Comment: I made one more update to fix a bug you may encounter. I hope this helps :)

Comment: I think I found that bug when testing it. I found another, if I use the values 1200x600, the ratio does not change. 1201x600 does however.

Comment: Yes I just realized I made one more mistake. Very unlikely to happen but in your case it did. If the heightRatio and the widthRatio manage to be the exact same, then nothing will happen. To remedy this just change widthRatio > heightRatio to widthRatio >= heightRatio. Glad this helped!

Comment: And that's the bug I found!

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide whether you will scale by the ratio of `height/maxHeight` or `width/maxWidth` then see which one you can use without making the other dimension too big. Another way of thinking is asking: if we maximize the width, does the height get too big? If not maximize the width, otherwise maximize the height. Either way, we scale by the same scale for width and height so the aspect ratio stays the same. (You would probably want to add sanity checks for divide by zero)

```js
function resize(size, max){ 
  // can we maximize the width without exceeding height limit? 
  let resize_factor = (size.height / ( size.width/max.width)) <= max.height
  ? size.width/max.width
  : size.height/max.height

 return {width: size.width/resize_factor, height: size.height/resize_factor}
}

let max = {
  width: 100,
  height: 50
}

console.log(resize({width: 500, height:50}, max))
console.log(resize({width: 500, height:1000}, max))
console.log(resize({width: 40, height:10}, max))
console.log(resize({width: 1, height:2}, max))
console.log(resize({width: 2, height:1}, max))
```